# Specify Range at first position in plot in R

Tags: r

I try to specify the X axis in my plot to Begin at 10, and then show a label every 5 steps, here is what i defined so far:

```
 vec<-(46, 30, 20, 11, 40, 29, 28, 11, 15, 17)
 plot(vec, col="blue", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
 axis(1, at = seq(10, 50, by = 5), las = 2)
```

This command is showing me the axis numbers every fifths time, but the axis doesn't start at 10, I mean it starts, but the axis is not at the first point (so 46), but starts somewhere in the middle of my function.
I want the first "46" to be the value of the first x-value which should be 10.

However, I am a real beginner in R so if someone could suggest me any nice documentation or tutorials that would be really helpful, thanks! I googled but I still didn't find anything nice and explained step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following I added a vector x. Note that the vector should run till 55 (with steps of 5) if you want to display every point. Is this what you were searching for?

```
vec<-c(46, 30, 20, 11, 40, 29, 28, 11, 15, 17)
x<-seq(10,55,5)
plot(x, vec)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? still get error messages:
Error in xy.cord, x and y lenghts differ

Comment: The vectors x and vec should have the same number of elements (in this case 10)

Comment: Oh yes tis is exactly what I wanted, thank you!
Is it possible to achieve this with limits and xaxp--I was searching in the internet long but none of those commands worked for me

Comment: And what if I want to plot another function? it will now work right, I mean another in the same function so
ploxt(x, fu1, fu)